# HttpClient WebRequestHandler not capturing all cookies

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I'm making a POST request to a web site to send username/login information in order to get a cooking containing an authentication token.  I build, test, and debug my process running in a console application, then I set it to run as part of a Windows Service.

When I am running in the console app, there are 2 cookies being returned from the post request: the JSESSIONID and the AuthToken.  After I deploy and run it in the Windows Service, I only see the JSESSIONID.

I set up Fiddler to watch the windows service, and I can see the AuthToken being passed back in the response to my post request, but I am unable to get it from the cookie container.

Additionally, if I install the process on my local machine, and run through my Fiddler proxy, I am able to get the AuthToken, but if I disable the proxy, no AuthToken is contained in the cookies.GetCookies result.

I'm at a loss as to why it will operate fine when running as a console app on my local machine, but the AuthToken fails to return when run as a service on a remote machine.

My local machine is running .net 4.7, and the server where the service is installed is running 4.5.2.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public string SubmitPost(Uri uri, string action, string contentPost, bool putRequest)
    {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        WebRequestHandler handler = new WebRequestHandler();
            handler.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://<FIDDLER PROXY>:8888", false, new string[] {});
        X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate2.CreateFromSignedFile(m_CertPath);
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
        string resultContent = "";

        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {

            AddClientHeadersForPost(uri, client);
            cookies.Add(uri, m_jar);

            var content = new StringContent(contentPost, Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            content.Headers.ContentLength = contentPost.Length;


            HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsync(action, content).Result;
            resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();

            Logger.InfoFormat("{0} cookies", responseCookies.Count());
            foreach (Cookie item in responseCookies)
            {
                Logger.InfoFormat("Cookie: {0}", item.Name);
                if (item.Name.Contains("auth"))
                {
                        Logger.InfoFormat("Auth Token: {0}", item.Value);
                }
                m_jar.Add(item);
            }
        }
        return (resultContent);
    }

    protected virtual void AddClientHeadersForPost(Uri uri, HttpClient client)
    {
        client.BaseAddress = uri;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "<HOST URL>");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Origin", "<ORIGIN URL>");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "*/*");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("DNT", "1");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Referer", "<REFERER URL>");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-CSRF-TOKEN", m_csrf);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-2-CSRF-TOKEN", m_sppCSRF);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Connection", "keep-alive");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you think the cookie is stored on the service? Normally the cookies are stored in the use settings.  When you run on a server you are running as a guest account with little privileges.  You need to have the service run as a user account on the server.  So an admin has to have the service run with different credentials.

Comment: @jdweng the service is installed and running as a user account.

Comment: Some progress has been made.  @jdweng I moved the service to a different server and set the logon user to an admin user.  I then went into internet options for that user and white-listed all cookies for the website I'm trying to authenticate with.  I can now run the service successfully, but I still can't install it using the same setup on our main server for some reason.  More investigation.

Comment: The environmental variables must be setup different on the two servers for the admin account.  I would logon to both servers and then open a cmd.exe and type >set This will get a list of environmental variables.